# Is it possible to enable MathJax in Light Table MarkDown?

Tags: markdown, mathjax, lighttable

I'm using [Light Table](http://lighttable.com/) to edit MarkDown, using the [lt-markdown plugin](https://github.com/MarcoPolo/lt-markdown). It doesn't seem to support MathJax. Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any existing support for it but I don't think it would be too hard to add a feature or setting to do so. Create an issue to request it at [the plugin's GitHub repo](https://github.com/MarcoPolo/lt-markdown). If you can, submit a PR with the changes.

Based on my cursory reading of the plugin's code, suitable `script` elements for the MathJax files should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I might have to take matters in my own hands.